# SQL finding previous 2 months

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the report of previous 2 months from the current month. How can I get that? For example,

if I execute a query on June , I need to get the April and May months sales report.
How can I do that? I tried 
Dateadd(month, -2, month(getdate())) but I did not get any result.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: [Provide a complete, minimal, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: when I executed this select dateadd(month,-2, getdate()), I got the result as 2016-04-27 13:11:34.797. What I need is just the month (i.e 4 in this case)

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of the month from two months ago:

```
DATEPART(month, Dateadd(month, -2, getdate()))
```

Comment: Thank you Tony! This is what I want